# Web API 2 OData error message returned as XML

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a batch request to an OData Web API that is called through a service proxy:

```
_productService.AttachTo("Products", product1);
_productService.UpdateObject(product1);
_productService.AttachTo("Products", product2);
_productService.UpdateObject(product2);
_productService.AttachTo("Products", product3);
_productService.UpdateObject(product3);

_productService.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

This hits the patch method of the ProductsController. Specifically the return BadRequest line if the request is invalid:

```
public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Product> patch)
{

    Product product = db.Products.Find(key);

    patch.Patch(product);

    HttpActionContext actionContext = new HttpActionContext(ControllerContext, Request.GetActionDescriptor());

    if (!Configuration.Services.GetBodyModelValidator().Validate(maintenance, typeof(Product), Configuration.Services.GetModelMetadataProvider(), actionContext, String.Empty))
    {
        return BadRequest(actionContext.ModelState);
    }
    else
    {
```

An error message is raised that is of type DataServiceRequestException. Its Response property contains a collection of System.Data.Services.Client.ChangeOperationResponse. Each of these has Error, Headers and StatusCode properties. My problem is that the error property is an xml string eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code />
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The request is invalid.</m:message>
    <m:innererror>
        <m:message>BookedForDate : 'Booked For Date' must not be empty.&#xD;\n</m:message>
        <m:type></m:type>
        <m:stacktrace></m:stacktrace>
    </m:innererror>
</m:error>
```

And I want to extract certain parts of this to return to the client.

Do I have to parse the XML or is there a way that I can have this returned as an Exception object or cast it as an object instead?

Thanks for any help or thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I used something along the lines of this to return the message part of the error. You have to look at the inner exception and use the namespace when querying the nodes or nothing is returned.

var doc = XDocument.Parse(e.InnerException.Message);

var msg = from node in doc.Root.Elements(doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + innererror").Elements(doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + "message")
select node.Value;

return msg.LastOrDefault();

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I little bit update code from scidec

```
  private string ExtractMessage(Exception e)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(e.InnerException.Message);

        var nspace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("m"); // .GetDefaultNamespace();
        var msg = from node in doc.Root.Elements(nspace + "innererror")
                    .Elements(nspace + "internalexception")
                    .Elements(nspace + "message")
                  select node.Value;

        return msg.LastOrDefault();
    }
```